# How do I connect to a PyDev project from Django?

Tags: python, django, message-queue, zeromq, pyzmq

The core logic rests in a Python project, which is ready, and I am creating the UI using Django framework. The Python project uses ZMQ for messaging.

Is it wise to connect Django to ZMQ (from the Python project) to send and receive values? I am dealing with MultiAgent systems, and the core project is all about controlling few hardware devices in buildings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's in fact, a recognized pattern for solutions like you're working on.

I gathered for you some links that show diferent approaches:

[Task queuing in Django with ZeroMQ](http://glitterbug.in/blog/task-queuing-in-django-with-zeromq-5/show/)

[Long Running Taks in Web App/Django](http://zderadicka.eu/long-running-taks-in-web-appdjango/)

This it's about [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html), but since [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) is a MOM (**[Message Oriented Middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware)**) too it might worth take a look this article: [Django and asynchronous jobs](http://www.davidfischer.name/2010/09/django-and-asynchronous-jobs/)

You might find interesting this package/application too: [Django-ztask](http://zeromq.org/story:3)

I hope you find the ansewr you're looking for.